# JPA/HIBERNATE Handle non POJO entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, hql, pojo

I have three classes. ClassA and ClassB are classical POJO entity mapped in database. I want a third ClassC to perform a specific and complex query in database (not mapped with any table) using HQL. Is that possible to add @Entity annotation on ClassC and persist it for reading only?

I am going through the documentation to figure out a way to map the following (sample) sql statement:

```
select 
 a.id, b.name, c.city
from
 emp a, identity b, address c
where
 a.id = b.id and a.id = c.id
```

I *don't* want to create domain objects and mapping for emp, identity and address.

All I want is to have one object, mapped to the output of the sql statement.

```
public class Data {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String city;
 // ... and other details ...
}
```

Technically, this should be the job of a stored procedure or a view. Unfortunately, I cannot change the database.

Any help / pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: why you want to create a class with @Entity just for creating HQL query? You have to use Entity annotation only if the class has a mapping table in DB.

Comment: Actually  i want classC to perform some reports. And i want to use this class like i use classA or ClassB with @Entity annotation. In this classC every field is a result of specific HQL request so that my application still matches the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your very complex SQL query as a view and map your entity to that. Basically, a view is just a read-only table (you can make it as a read-write in Oracle but that is another story :) ) so any hibernate mapping would work fine as a read-only entity. I've done that before but years ago using plain Hibernate and hbm files. I have never tried using JPA or annotations but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's great approach but i don't want to modify the database just perform some HQl requests and save each HQL request into fields of classC and i want to use classC like i use an @Entity class.